# Windows 10: Can't install a Python Github module after i cloned a repo to a local Windows pc

Tags: python, windows, module, installation, clone

I want to install this github repo: https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel on my local PC Windows 10.
But
2.) I tried this:
Download and extract the repo.zip file and open command prompt with RunAsAdmin mode and run this command.
- `python setup.py install` - but in which folder to run it ?
Then i got this result see following screenshots.

[Failure: Result from running - python setup.py install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGREC.png)

Comment: On their repo, they have mentioned the pypi install. You can download and install it by `pip install eel`

Comment: Please don’t share information as images unless absolutely necessary (which isn’t the case here). What are you trying to do with the repo?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand this. I already did this but i also failured.              
Someone also mentioned this methode[absolute_path_to]\python.exe -m pip install 'module'. Where the -m (parameter should be important)